# How to delete History of installed packages

Tags: software-center, synaptic

I need to delete the Synaptic/Software Center history(commit logs). How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Install some porn apps and need to hide them?

Comment: But seriously, it is worth being clear why you need to delete it.  Installed and removed applications can leave other traces besides the apt/dpkg logs.

Comment: I am setting up a laptop for someone _extremely_ nosy. I'd rather they not look at the history and try uninstalling software I installed and trying to reinstall software that I uninstalled. If curiosity killed the cat, perhaps putting the next cat in a cage would keep it alive longer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove the history.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/apt/history.log /var/log/dpkg.log
```

I would advise to make a backup just in case!  That can be done by

```
mkdir ~/apt-logs
sudo cp /var/log/{dpkg,apt/history}.log ~/apt-logs
```

You also need `/var/log/dpkg.log`

Comment: You also need `/var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: I think there shouldn't be a ~ in front of the var folder's path.