# How to clear the history of Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

In the USC window and go to the History tab at the top, it records every of your installations, update, removal, please tell me how to clear them

---

I tried this: [How to delete History of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108936/how-to-delete-history-of-installed-packages)

But it didn't work, after deleting var/log/apt/history.log /var/log/dpkg.log, there are sill many text files in the folders which referred to the history of USC.