# How do I clear Software Center history?

Tags: software-center, history, cleanup

I have old Software Center history and I would like to clear it all.

I tried

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/apt/history.log /var/log/dpkg.log
```

but it did not work.

Comment: I really need to scare some users from using `rm -rf`... but anyways, do you really know where the software center logs?

Comment: Close voters: why is this unclear? He wants to clear the Software Center History (whatever is in the "History" tab).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/214863/

Answer (score 0):

You were close—Software Center just [keeps a cache](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntuone-control-tower/software-center/stable-5-6/view/head:/softwarecenter/db/history_impl/apthistory.py#L112) of the APT history in your home folder. If you need to wipe it:

1. Delete the APT history log, `/var/log/apt/history.log*`. (Don't forget the [rotated](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/logrotate) log files.)
2. Delete the Software Center's [pickled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickle_%28Python%29) cache, `~/.cache/software-center/apthistory.p`, from every user's home folder.

I'm not sure why your question was down-voted.

Comment: Presumably `/var/log/dpkg.log` *is* actually used as well.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be used in USC's history, from my brief test and from skimming the code linked above. You'd want to delete it if you were trying to hide having installed something but that's such a tricky topic I don't feel comfortable providing advice here; I'd likely miss something subtle and I don't want to provide a false sense of security.